# Double username/password validation on MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Hi,

I have built a ASP.NET MVC website that uses Membership, this works fine. During the sites beta test I need to ensure that only beta testers are able to visit my website so a second(really the first login) login has to be made.

The question is how I can do this as easy and fast as possible without involving the current membership setup?

It's okay if the username and password is static/hardcoded but it's important that once the outer login is completed, no more login requests will be made during the session. It's important that the current MVC Membership works as before.

Comment: Why not just add a *beta* role?

Comment: The problem is that this webpages should be tested both with and without a membership account. But let us look closer at this, in the current membership I got two roles, User=0 and Admin=1. In some places a validation of roles could be done with CurrentRole > 0 So I will have to track down these places and solve it. The BetaUser could be added between User and Admin (BetaUser=1). This will make it possible to test the webpage when logedin, but how to test without a membership account?

Comment: Use some means external to the website's code to control that, such as a VLAN or packet filtering. The problem is, your tests would not be valid if you added an extra level of auth to it, because you would be altering the code just for the test... the very code you are testing.

Comment: I see. I have checked the webhotel and there is somthing called "activate base authentication". When visiting the site a username and password dialog will appear, could this be the solution? I have however not found where I set the username and password yet.

Comment: That *could* very well provide what you need, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a new role(tester). This did involve alot of refactoring but it seems to work really well.

When the testuser is loging in and the site is set in test mode the returned user will be "" witch means no user.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Forms and BasicAuthentication modes do not work together. This is because there is only one "IPrincipal" variable on the HttpContext (IMHO called User). But if you were using two different authentication schemes at the same time, the last one would always win. This is why this is not supported. People would get unexpected results.

But it can be done pretty easily: You need to implement basic authentication yourself. This can be done during the BeginRequest event. You can hook it up in Global.asax (preferred) or in an HTTP module.

Implementing BasicAuth is not complicated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

If you want to hardcode the credentials inside of the basic auth code you will be done in 30min.